# Is meat eating outside of yajnas considered sin for Varnas like kshatriyas and sudras too?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, varna, kshatriya

Just like all religions Hinduism also maintains that eating animals outside of religious sphere, without offering it to god (s) leads to sin/bad karma, is this applicable unto kshatriyas too?

Answer (score 7):

As far as i have read, eating meat without any rituals is never really recommended in *any Hindu scriptures*.

> A Brahmana, engaged in the celebration of a religious sacrifice,
>   becomes degraded by not taking meat.
>
> A Kshatriya should eat the cooked flesh of a quarry after having
>   propitiated therewith the gods and his departed manes. A Vaishya can
>   take meat, lawfully obtained for money, after having worshipped
>   therewith his departed manes. (56 57)
>
> **A twice-born one, by eating the cooked flesh of an animal wantonly
>   slaughtered (not killed in any sacrifice), suffers the pangs of hell
>   for eternal time, or as long as the sun and stars would shine in
>   heaven.**
>
> A Brahmana, by abjuring meat, acquires the merit of a horse-sacrifice,
>   all his desires are fructified, and he becomes an emancipated self
>   even though he be a householder. (58)
>
> **Vyasa Smriti's Chapter 3 verses.**

These verses prove that the act is not recommended for everyone from the Brahmins to the Vaishyas.

A slightly different perspective however is found [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20584/4732).

EDIT1:

Adding a few relevant verses from the Manu Smriti:

> 5.31. ’**The consumption of meat (is befitting) for sacrifices**,’that is declared to be a rule made by the gods; **but to persist (in using
>   it) on other (occasions) is said to be a proceeding worthy of
>   Rakshasas.**
>
> 5.32. He who eats meat, when he honours the gods and manes, commits no sin, whether he has bought it, or himself has killed (the animal), or
>   has received it as a present from others.
>
> 5.33. **A twice-born man who knows the law, must not eat meat except in conformity with the law;** for if he has eaten it unlawfully, he
>   will, unable to save himself, be eaten after death by his (victims).

EDIT2:

The following passage from the Devi Bhagavata Purana's 1st book sums it up.

> 57-61. Janaka said :-- “**The killing of animals in a sacrificial
>   ceremony is not killing; it is known as Ahimsâ; for that himsâ is not
>   from any selfish attachment; therefore when there is no such sacrifice
>   and the animals are killed out of selfish attachment, then that is
>   real himsâ; there is no other opinion in this.** Smoke arises from a
>   fire when fuels are placed in it; and smoke is not seen when no fuel
>   is added. So, O Munisattama! The himsâ, as prescribed in the Vedas, is
>   free from all blemishes, selfish attachment, etc., and therefore it is
>   unblameable.
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam 1.18**

So, for everyone the act is blameable, even for the Sudras.

Answer (score 4):

God created Varnas but Varnas are decided by Karma not by birth.

Its always sin.

God created our body like a vegetarian.

I have some facts that human is vegetarian:

1. **Nails**: All non-vegetarian have sharp nails(like: Cat, Dog, Tiger etc) but vegetarian don't have sharp nails(Human, Cow, Horse etc).
2. **Teeth**: All non-vegetarian have sharp teeth(like: Cat, Dog, Tiger etc) but vegetarian don't have sharp teeth(Human, Cow, Horse etc).
3. **Drinking**: All Non-vegetarian animals drink water from tongue but all vegetarian drinks water from lips.
4. **Digestions**: All Non-vegetarian animals can digest without cooked flesh but vegetation (Human) can't digest raw flesh(without cooked).

**Last and most important**

5. **Eyes**: At the time of birth all non-vegetarian have eyes closed and remain closed for 3-4 days but all vegetarian have opens their eyes instantly after birth.

Comment: God did create Varnas, atleast according to Vedas and bhagvad geeta.

Comment: Your answer is  Scientific than Religious or spiritual.

Comment: Our body is made by God, not by science. Science itself made by God. Our Vedas contains many scientific things.