# How non vegetarians are wrong?

Tags: food

I am a pure vegetarian and against non-veg and often I try to justify for this to my friends using scientific or logical proof.

I have seen in Bhagavat Gita and Manusmriti that vegetarian diet is preferred. But is there any justification given?

---

One reason I could find that. Plants dont have brain so that cannot feel the pain.
Are there any other reasons?

Comment: Related:  [Does Bhagavad Gita say anything about whether a person should eat Vegetarian or Non Vegetarian food?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29476/21103) , [Do any scriptures describe fish to be vegetarian/Sattvic?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23344/21103), [What are Tamasic, Rajasic and Sattvic foods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2659/21103), [Why can we eat 'living' plants but not 'living' animals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/97/21103)

Comment: Strictly speaking, eggs (the eggs we get are all unfertilized-there's nothing alive in them), mushroom, onion, garlic etc. don't have brains either, nor can they feel pain. But it is sinful to eat them according to scripture; as sinful as meat.

Comment: @sahdg Use [edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/43156/edit) button to revise the question. Add answer only if you're actually answering question. Visit [answer]

Comment: "One reason I could find that. Plants don't have brain so that cannot feel the pain. Are there any other reasons?" - such logical/scientific reasons have nothing to do with Hinduism so off-topic for this site.