# Is non-veg really banned in hinduism?

Tags: dharma, sin, food, non-vegetarian

I personally believe that eating non veg is a sin for any hindu,but there are many sects in hinduism which allow non veg such as bengalis offer fishes to kaali ma , a brahmin sect in bihar do also eat fish , south indian coastal hindus do also eat fishes, so i just wanna ask why there is irony in hinduism?

Comment: See this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20584/4732

Comment: Going against scripture is sin. What about conscience? Does any scripture talk about this? Sometimes feel that even chopping plant is sin. Only fruits that are ready to drop are 'ok'. So if totally sinless, we may starve!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wash away sin after unconsciously consuming non-vegetarian food?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/how-to-wash-away-sin-after-unconsciously-consuming-non-vegetarian-food)

Comment: Further, you probably mean 'apparent contradictions. Hinduism is a British word created for a mass of different sects with different beliefs, and adapting with time. No contradiction at all.

Comment: @ajitdas - sin is not binary, but a scale from 0 to 100. there are parivrajaka sanyasis who even today follow the rules you said - they only eat naturally fallen down grains or fruits - this is called kapota-vritthi (like a pigeon). there is another types - aja-gara vritthi (python) - who sit in a place, and only eat what naturally falls in their lap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Hindus vegetarian? What is the real meaning of the word 'mamsah' (मांसः) or meat?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/why-are-hindus-vegetarian-what-is-the-real-meaning-of-the-word-mamsah-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%82%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%83)

Answer (score 3):

Non-vegetarian food is not actually 'banned' in hinduism. There are Scriptures which permit the consumption of the flesh of certain animals, albeit with certain restrictions and rules.

**Vamana Purana 14.60**

[image]

**Agni-Purana 168.13-21**

> So also pelugavya and peyūṣa which cause excess of phlegm and
> vṛtā-kṛsarasaṃyāva, pāyasa, cakes, fried eatables made of
> flour, **flesh of animal not prepared for a sacrifice, food intended
> for the gods, oblations and all (kinds of) milks except (those) of
> cows, she-buffaloes and goats are prohibited** as well as their waters
> ten days old. **The hare, porcupine, godhā (a kind of an alligator),
> rhinoceros and tortoise are (those among) the (animals having) five
> nails (whose flesh) could be eaten. The remaining ones are prohibited.
> One may eat fish such as the pāṭhīna (a kind of sheat-fish), rohita
> and lion-faced fish.**

Certain kinds of flesh such as Fish etc. are permitted to be eaten after offering them to deities or brahmanas although others are forbidden.

[**Padma Purana, Svarga Khanda, Chapter 56**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365275.html)

> 31b-46. He should not eat (the flesh of) a crane, a swan, a gallinule,
> a sparrow, a parrot, so also an osprey, a patridge, a goose, a cuckoo,
> crows, wagtails, a hawk, a vulture, so also an owl, a ruddy goose, a
> vulture (or a cock), a pigeon, a dove, a ṭiṭṭibha bird, a domestic
> cock, a lion, a tiger, a cat, a dog, a pig, a fox, a monkey and a
> donkey. He should not eat (the flesh of) serpents, deer, peacocks,
> aquatic animals, land-going animals. This is a settled rule. **O best
> ones, Prajāpati Manu has said that these animals with five claws may
> be always eaten: alligator, tortoise, hare, rhinoceros, porcupine. He
> may also eat fish with scales, and the flesh of (the deer called) ruru
> after having presented them to deities and brāhmaṇas, and not
> otherwise. O best brāhmaṇas, so also (the flesh of) a peacock, a
> patridge, a pigeon, a cātaka, rhinoceros, a crane, a swan. Thus said
> Prajāpati (Manu). These fish, viz. (the glittering fish) śapharī,
> siṃhatuṇḍa, paṭhīna and rohita are directed as fit to be eaten.**

It is said that one does not incur any sin if meat is eaten after offering it to deities or as a medicine.

**[Brahma Purana 113.111-112](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216270.html)**

> 111. The following can be eaten: hare, tortoise, alligator, porcupine and the fish with darts (?) The village boar and the cock should be
>      avoided.
>
> **112. In the following circumstances, even if one eats meat, one is not defiled: if it is the remnant of offerings unto the Pitṛs, Devas
> etc. or if it is cooked in Śrāddha at the request of the brahmins and
> is sprinkled with holy water or if it is taken as a medicine.**

**[Markandeya Purana Canto XXXV](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117071.html)**

> The hare, the tortoise, the go-sāmp,the porcupine, and the rhinoceros,
> my son,—these indeed may he eaten; and the domestic pig and fowl
> should he eschewed. The remains of food at a śrāddha after the pitṛs
> and gods and other recipients have been satisfied may be eaten at the
> desire of the brāhmans. A man who eats flesh that has been killed for
> the purpose of medicine is not defiled.

Same thing stated in Kurma PurAna, meat when eaten under injunctions or as medicine does not incur any sin.

**[Kurma Purana II.17.34-40](https://archive.org/details/kurma-purana-full-parts-1-and-2/page/429/mode/2up?view=theater)**

[image]

Use of Meat as medicine for certain conditions was common in Ayurveda. We see this in Ayurvedic Texts such as Charaka Samhita and other texts where meat is prescribed to certain patients too.

[**Charaka Samhita, Chikitsa sthana, Chapter 8**](https://archive.org/details/CharakaSamhitaTextWithEnglishTanslationP.V.Sharma/page/155/mode/2up?view=theater)

[image]

[image]

[**Agni Purana 279.19b-21**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083508.html)

> l9b-21. The juice of venison is commended as food for those suffering
> from pulmonary consumption. Horse-gram, green-gram, black pepper etc.
> and dry radish compounded with venison or cakes or **bird’s flesh or
> compounded with curd and pomegranade juice, dressed with the juice of
> citron, honey, grapes and vyoṣa (dried ginger, long and black pepper)
> and cooked barley, wheat and śāli rice should be given as food to an
> asthma patient.**

Comment: @Rickross from what I have heard it is only a sin to kill and consume an animal for pleasure or sense gratification. Even Aryuveda permits the eating of meat for Kshatryias especially. Rama hunted or thought he was hunting a deer. Krishna in the Bhagavad Gita 6.11 (To practice Yog, one should make an āsan (seat) in a sanctified place, by placing Kuśh grass, deerskin, and a cloth, one over the other. The āsan should be neither too high nor too low.), so Krishna himself permits deer skin for spiritual use. Not to mention Pashubali a necessary Vedic Animal sacrifice ritual.

Answer (score 0):

Whosoever says that meat eating is banned in Sanatana Dharma has no knowledge of either our Itihasas or Vedas. For example, here is what **Sri Rama tells Vaali in Kishkindha Kanda, 18th Sarga of Valmiki Ramayana:**

[image]

**Meaning**: Those who eat meat will undeniably kill animals, w hether they are  sprinting or standing steadily, fully dismayed or undismayed, vigilant or unvigilant, and even if they are facing away, in that there is no sin.

Answer (score -1):

```
  "Non-Veg banned in Hinduism"
```

DEFINITELY YES: by SANAATANA DHARMA

Non-Veg(though of various types, understood as animal flesh) eaten  by humans is considered as sin-bound and the consumer has to bear

1. The brutality of sins
2. Wrath of God
3. Praayaschitta : tough ways to forgive his/her sins
4. Restriction from addictive effects created by such foods
5. In future, the cost and labour to protect species of animals/ birds he/she had eaten for one's hunger.
6. Must take bath in Holy waters in old age when body is unable to accept such fleshy foods(foods that may induce AATMAHATYAA duing last stages of life ruining one's own soul.

Those meat consumers in Hinduism are subject to above 6 examinations though they unknowingly / knowingly consumed.

HENCE VARNAASHRAMA DHARMA is emphasized for humans for different food habits according to KARMA VIDHI. A human being born in KaliYuga can never be a SANAATANA DHARMI without abandoning animal products of sufferings.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. You must provide a scriptural source reference for your answers in this site. Please modify your post accordingly.