# Does eating a non vegetarian based food incur sin in our lives?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian

Throughout the world , meat eating has become a daily routine in our lives. The meat consumed comes from torturing and mercilessly killing animals like pig, goat, chicken etc.

Hinduism has always considered in the principles of non violence and peace, so it it right to eat meat as our meal after such misdeeds are done? What will be the sin and how will god make us repay ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wash away sin after unconsciously consuming non-vegetarian food?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/how-to-wash-away-sin-after-unconsciously-consuming-non-vegetarian-food)

Comment: @rickross , does eating meat that are bought from shops and butcher house count as the food sacrificed for god? I as common householder donot eat meat bought from the market and cook it . I have never as such, specifically sacrificed any animal for the deities. From childhood as most typical Bengali people we cook mutton or chicken on Sundays and Wednesdays /Mondays just because we crave for it . So shall I stop consuming it to get rid of sins? Thank you.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas read manu 5.51

Comment: You can create a new question for asking if non veg person who eats meat, turns veg, what atonement should he do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From holy vedas
Atharva Veda says:

(Atharva Veda 10.1.29)
Abstract meaning: It is definitely a great sin to kill innocents.  Do not kill our cows, horses and people.

Atharva Veda 8.6.23
Abstract Meaning: We ought to destroy those who eat cooked as well as uncooked meat, meat involving destruction of males and females, fetuses and eggs.

(Atharva Veda 6.140.2)
Abstract meaning: You eat rice, barley, gram and sesame.  These cereals are specifically meant for you.  Do not kill those who are capable of being fathers and mothers

Yajur Veda 1.1
Abstract Meaning:  O human! Animals are Aghnya – NOT TO BE KILLED.  PROTECT THE ANIMALS.

From Manusmriti

5.51 He who approves, he who cuts, he who kills, he who buys and sells, he who cooks, he who serves and he who eats it are ‘slayers’—(51).

From mahabharat

> स्वमांसं परमांसेन यो वर्धयितुमिइच्छति ।
>
> नाति क्षुद्रतरस्त्स्मात्स नृशंसतरो नर: ।।
>
> People who wish to increase their flesh by eating other's flesh are
> the worst kind of creatures.

What will happen for meat eaters

"He who desires to augment his own flesh by eating the flesh of other creatures, lives in misery in whatever species he may take his [next] birth." (Mahabharata, Anu.115.47)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, meat that is not consumed under scriptural injunctions is advised to be avoided.

[Mahabharata Book 13, Section CLXII](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b127.htm)

> One does not incur any fault or stain by eating the meat of animals
> slain in sacrifices with the aid of Tantras from the Yajur Veda. The
> flesh of the back-bone, or that of animals not slain in sacrifice,
> should be avoided even as one avoids the flesh of one's own son.

Comment: Can you tell me which tantra exists before mahabharat existed??

Comment: The mahabharata does not tell us the names of the specific texts it talks about in the above instance. So it's not possible to name them. But the fact that  tantras did exist is accepted in the mahabharata at other places too

Answer (score 0):

There are verses in Smriti shastras that condemn eating meat and there are verses that say in certain situations meat eating is allowed. In a nutshell, the point can be summarized by the following verse.

> There is no sin in eating meat, in (drinking) spirituous liquor, and in carnal intercourse, for that is the natural way of created beings, but abstention brings great rewards. - *Manusmriti 5.56*

Reference -

1. [Manusmriti translated by George Buhler](https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/manusmriti.html)