# According to Dvaita theory why did the Paramatma populate the earth?

Tags: brahman, dvaita, jiva, vaikuntha

Paramatma and Jeevatma live happily in the Vaikuntha Loka. Jeevatma is doing his karma by praying to Paramatma. Paramatma is doing his Karma by bestowing blessing on his followers.

Now my question is: If everything was so fine in Vaikuntha Loka, then why did Paramatma created the human body which is made up of filth and is the cause of suffering?

Comment: There was never a starting point for Samsara.  Samsara has existed for all eternity.  Every Jiva has had infinitely many past births going infinitely far back in time.

Comment: The only people who believe that the Jiva was in Vaikuntha before it entered Samsara are ISKCON people, who believe in a Vedantic philosophy called Achintya Bheda Abheda, not Dvaita.

Comment: We existed before this period and we will exist after this period.("Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.") But why did God chose to exist on Earth which is the cause of suffering? Why are not we all in the Vaikuntha already?

Comment: _"Why are not we all in the Vaikuntha already?"_ To live with God in his dhaam, one has to proof himself whether he/she is worthy of living in Vaikuntha or not. To check if you are worthy or not, God first send everyone on Earth. And what ever we do on Earth, by those acts of our God judge us and decides whether we are worthy of Vaikuntha or not. By seeing our all karma of our life God decides we will go to Heaven or Hell or Vaikuntha. No one can go Vaikuntha directly without proving himself worthy Because there is no shortcut of attaining Lord Vishnu.

Comment: OK. How can I prove myself worthy ?

Comment: You can prove yourself worthy by not carrying any punya or sins(paapa). Because if you will carry punya phal then you will get heaven and if you will carry paapa phal then you will get Hell. And if you will not have any punya or paapa phal on your death time then you will get moksha. Read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/giving-alms-donation-charity-with-the-intention-of-getting-merit-will-give-me/20792#20792) to get an idea about how to get rid of your punya and paapa phal.

Comment: There is one more way of attaining moksha. Read this to know about alternate way.. [Do grave sinners attain moksha if they remember Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/do-grave-sinners-attain-moksha-if-they-remember-lord-vishnu)

Comment: See related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16683/2790 *Is there the first birth of a jiva soul in the material world or not?*

Comment: @brahmajijnasa From Advaita philosophy it is clear that world is mythya or illusion or dream like. Any jiva's birth will turn out be an illusion,or dream like. In other words we can not raise the question which you have raised because the world itself is a like a lie. However from Dvaita point of view, Jeevatma definitely takes birth and enters into a special samsara called Vaikuntha which remains eternal. The jeevatma in the special samsara can see,hear , touch , feel , taste etc... just like us. I don't know why we should not call Vaikuntha as mythya too?

Comment: *Jeevatma definitely takes birth and enters into a special samsara called Vaikuntha* -- there is no birth and death and samsara in Vaikuntha. Vaikuntha is the world of liberation from karma and samsara (repeated births and deaths), only liberated souls live there, it's the state of moksha. Vaishnavas understand things much different than Advaitins do. Vaikuntha is not unreal but is reality per the Vaishnava understanding.